# Plasmashell Crashes/Doesn't Start?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 18.04

I've just done a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04, and was in the process of setting the environment up (Installing new programs, the usual after a fresh install), but plasmashell crashed at some point and I killed it using `killall plasmashell`, and ever since, it refuses to start. As I observed in (Edit 2), this was due to closing the Terminal window while the process was running. Plasmashell no longer starts at startup, and just displays a blinking line in the top left corner, and the cursor, nothing else.

Is there any way I can fix this? I'm on the live USB right now. Every time I try to start the OS plasmashell doesn't boot. Normally I would use `Alt + F2` to bring up a Terminal window, but this doesn't work, I tried`Ctrl + Alt + F7` in an attempt to bring up a terminal window for the local session, but this just loads indefinitely as well.

**EDIT 0:**
A description of the actual process that happens at boot is that the Kubuntu symbol appears then the mouse cursor appears and then nothing happens after that. I can move the cursor, but the screen never emerges from black.

**EDIT 1:**
This problem also appears in the live USB version if the commands `killall plasmashell && plasmashell` are executed, and the terminal that the commands were issued from is closed a few seconds later (Giving time for the plasmashell to run). The screen turns black with just the cursor around, as if plasmashell didn't restart. This breaks from the behaviour of the previous Kubuntu version, in which plasmashell would restart after I did this.

**EDIT 2:** I have the logs from `/var/logs` but I'm not sure which ones are most relevant.

Comment: 1) If it's a regular install why the need to "typically start it using `kstart plasmashell`"? 2) Since you mentioned `aptik` in your other question, maybe *don't* use `aptik` in case you're going to do a new install?

Comment: @DKBose I'm fairly certain it wasn't `aptik` due to me not having the backup data I thought I had. Nothing happened with it. There was no data to restore from for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to Nvidia. I am running an AMD video card and since an update a few days ago, Plasma is crashing on login (all user accounts) and attempting to start it manually results in the same.

Comment: I don't really think that's an answer though. Also, if you think this is a good question, don't forget to upvote it. Did anything you did solve the issue?

Comment: this is definitely not an answer, should be a comment.